# Python 2.7 - Remove item from list y without removing that same item from the list x that it was created from

Tags: python, list, python-2.7

In python I have a list variable. I then create a new variable and equal it to the first list variable. I want to be able to remove an item from the second variable without affecting the first. My code below is an example of what I am trying to do

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y = x
y.remove(4)
```

However, it removes 4 from both x and y. when I run

```
print y
print x
```

I get

```
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
```

How can I in this example only remove 4 from y but not from x?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=x.copy()
y.remove(4)
print (x)
print (y)
>>> 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>>
```

You have to copy the first list, then it will be what you want.

```
x = [0,1,2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9,10]
y=list(x)
y.remove(4)
print (x)
print(y)
>>> 
[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
[0, 1, 2, 3, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]
>>>
```

Python 2x. doesnt have 'copy' method so, the first list defined again.

Comment: Why do you have to copy it first?

Comment: @wwii Because lists are mutable objects in python, and so assignment works more like a reference than a copy.

Comment: That's how Python doing different processes on 'same' variables(actually they are not same)

Comment: I copy and pasted this into python and got this error:                  Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\Users\Smith\Desktop\test.py", line 2, in <module>
    y=x.copy()
AttributeError: 'list' object has no attribute 'copy'

Comment: @byurocks23 I just run this codes everything is fine?

Comment: @byurocks23 Instead of `y = x.copy()`, write `y = list(x)`. I don't think the `copy` method exists in Python 2, only in Python 3.

Comment: @byurocks23 Oh do you using Python 2?

Comment: @jme all names are references to the objects they have been assigned to, not just mutable objects - [Other languages have *variables*](http://python.net/~goodger/projects/pycon/2007/idiomatic/handout.html#other-languages-have-variables)

Comment: @byurocks23 Check my answer again.Second codes what you need.

Comment: @wmii I agree. I said assignment of a mutable object works "more like a reference", drawing a comparison to other languages. That's why you need to copy the list.

Comment: @byurocks23 if it solved your problem please check it as answer

Comment: I still need to wait three minutes till it will let me.

Answer (score 1):

You want to make `y` a deepcopy of `x`. You can either use `copy.deepcopy` or use a "full slice" of the list.

```
y = copy.deepcopy(x)
```

or

```
y = x[:]
```

Now, `x` and `y` are labels of two different objects and, thus, operations on `y` won't affect `x`.